# NoMethodError: undefined method `RuntimeError' 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I wrote some code in a Ruby library (incidentally used in Rails) that raised a RuntimeError somewhat like below:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(opts = {})
     # do stuff
     thing = opts[:thing]
     raise RuntimeError "must have a thing!" unless thing.present? && thing.is_a?(Thing)
     # more stuff
  end
end
```

and when I ran my fresh new rspec spec over it, which looks somewhat like:

```
it "should raise an error if we don't pass a thing" do
  lambda {
    my_class = MyClass.new(:thing => nil)
  }.should raise_exception(RuntimeError)
end
```

I kept getting something weird:

```
expected RuntimeError, got 
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `RuntimeError' for #<MyClass:0xb5acbf9c>>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may already have spotted the problem... ah, single-character bugs, doncha love em?

Here it is.

WRONG:

```
 raise RuntimeError "must have a thing!" unless thing.present? && thing.is_a?(Thing)
```

RIGHT:

```
 raise RuntimeError, "must have a thing!" unless thing.present? && thing.is_a?(Thing)
```

of course, you can also just go ahead and leave out the RuntimeError entirely:

```
 raise "must have a thing!" unless thing.present? && thing.is_a?(Thing)
```

because it's the default anyways...

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a comma:

```
raise RuntimeError, "must have a thing!" unless thing.present? && thing.is_a?(Thing)
                  ^
```

Comment: ah - you answered before I got my answer up :) This was actually a "pre-solved" question... I figured somebody else would have the same problem and might want the answer too...

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little bit more explanation: in Ruby, there is an ambiguity between variable references and message sends.

```
foo
Foo
```

Could *either* mean "dereference the variable named `foo` (or `Foo`)" *or* "send the message `:foo` (or `:Foo`) with an empty argument list to the default receiver".

This ambiguity is resolved as follows:

1. If `foo` starts with a lower-case letter, it is assumed to be a message send, unless the parser has seen an assignment to `foo` before, in which case it is treated as a variable dereference. (Note that the assignment only needs to *parsed*, not executed; `if false then foo = nil end` is perfectly fine.)
2. If `Foo` starts with an uppercase letter, it is treated as a variable (or rather constant) dereference, unless you pass an argument list (even an empty one), in which case it is treated as a message send.

In this case, `RuntimeError` is treated as a message send, because it has an argument list: `"must have a thing!"`. This is, of course, because of another of Ruby's peculiarities, namely that it allows you to leave out the parentheses around an argument list, as long it is unambiguous.

IOW: the whole thing is interpreted roughly as

```
self.RuntimeError("must have a thing!")
```

Comment: are you serious that `if false: foo = nil` can overwrite my call to local methods, if it btw is into a class??